# How to return from method where an error is encountered but type is expected

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Assume I have a method that returns a `List<int>` and that in the process of getting this `List<int>` an error occurs such that the data cannot be gathered. What is the best way to handle this exception within the method? The program is expecting the method to return a List but since, for whatever reason , an error occurred it can no longer do this. What should I return from the method? Is it a custom exception that is caught by the calling code?

```
private List<int> GetData()
{
  List<in> theData = new List<int>();
  theData = ProcessThatGetsData(); //Error occurs in here
  return theData;  //What should be returned here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch the exception and handle it, one way to do it is to use a return object like this:

```
        private OperationResult GetData()
        {
            List<int> theData = new List<int>();
            try
            {
                theData = ProcessThatGetsData(); //Error occurs in here
                return new OperationResult { Success = true, Data = theData };
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                return new OperationResult { Success = false };
            }
            return theData;  //What should be returned here?
        }

        public class OperationResult
        {
            public bool Success { get; set; }
            public IList<int> Data { get; set; }
        }
```

This is an option, however my preference would be **not** to put the try catch statement in here, only at the layer you really need it ... in which case your code doesn't need to change or worry about return type.

Wherever you call the GetData method, put the call in a try/catch statement and you should be OK.

Remember, always treat exceptions at the level where they have to be treated, don't over do it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a custom exception that is caught by the calling code

Yes, just let exceptions occur, the calling methods are in charge of handling exceptions (by try-catch blocks).